# JavaScript - Writing indexOf and each

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, each, indexof

I'm trying to rewrite _.each and _.indexOf and it is throwing me for a loop.

My each function takes either an object or an array and passes tests set up.

```
_['each'] = function(collection, iterator) {
if (Array.isArray(collection) === false && typeof(collection) === 'object') {
  var values = Object.values(collection);
  var keys = Object.keys(collection);
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    iterator(values[i], keys[i], collection, i);
  }
} else {
  for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    iterator(collection[i], i, collection);
    }
  }
}
```

So I'm assuming this code is alright since it passes a preset test, but I'm not even sure about that. My question is, how would I write an indexOf() function that also uses the each() function? Each will run a function for every element and won't break, right? And I can't access the index via collection[i] because i is undefined in indexOf's scope. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure it's best to make `indexOf` use `each`. The two are different in how they operate, even though they'd eventually iterate. Even Underscore has different code for the two. You *could* probably generalise the iteration logic and both `indexOf` and `each` could utilise the same base code but you run the risk of the generic iteration being *too* generic and not that useful as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pseudo code, check if you need the full javascript code :

```
indexOf = function(element, array){

    // found index
    index = -1;


    // for each element, compare element, store index if found
    each array (function(e, i){

          // use cmp function to deep compare object/array as values
          if(e === element)
          {
              // remove condition for lastIndexOf
              if(index == -1)
              {
                 index = i;
              }
          }

    });

    // return found index
    return index;

}
```

Comment: Should be indexOf = function(array, element) to match with the given each function. And the comparison should have a check if you want to ensure the first occurrence is returned, if(e === element && index === -1). Thanks for the help!

Comment: your changes has been added :)